# How to load a .rda neuralnetwork model of R in python

Tags: python, r

I have done a binary classification model using `neuralnet()` function in  R. An example code is [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-neural-network-in-r-neuralnet-package/). I have done same network using python `keras`, which has less prediction accuracy due to its parameters adjustments. So i have saved the R's neural network model using `save(model_nnet, file = "/tmp/model_nnet.rda")` and loaded using `load(file = "/tmp/model_nnet.rda")`.

My question is can i load this file in python? and use it for some predicton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RData files are R's storage format for R objects, and so can contain complex data structures and metadata. This is not easy to translate into data formats for other languages.

You will have to load the RData file into R and write the components of the object you need to text files using other packages - for example you could write it to a JSON file using one of R's JSON packages, and then read it in using a Python JSON module. But you will have to manually extract the parameters and numbers and so o from your model fit and construct an object that can be written to JSON. Its possible someone has already done this for your class of object.